# shortest mysql OR logic/syntax for select statements

Tags: mysql

I would like to select a bunch of a data from my DB if certain conditions were met and i was wondering what the right way to do the logic would be.

for example, i want to do something like the following

```
SELECT * WHERE field1 = (A or B or C) and field2 = D and field 3 = (E or F), etc.
```

I'd prefer not to define each case individually and do something like the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IN` to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 IN (A, B, C) AND field2 = D AND field3 IN (E, F)
```

Read more about it [IN the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: Gotta love when I get in first with a detailed answer and a link to the docs but a later answer that ads no new info gets accepted @BenArnao

Answer (score 0):

How about...
SELECT * WHERE field1 IN (A , B , C) and field2 = D and field 3 IN (E , F), etc.